# Serverless CORS Error: Did not find method in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods'

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I tried using Serverless framework and have followed the guide to enable CORS.

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },  
    body: JSON.stringify({
        temperature: 30,
        locationId: event.queryStringParameters || event.queryStringParameters.id
    })
  };
```

And I also added in the `serverless.yml`.

```
functions:
  getListComment:
    handler: handler.getListComment
    events:
        - http:
            path: comments/list
            method: get
            cors: true
```

The final endpoint is here

```
https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list
```

Somewhat when I tried calling the endpoint via AJAX.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list',
        type: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert('test');
        }
    });
```

There is nothing happens.

The Firefox console shows this message

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list.
>   (Reason: Did not find method in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’).

And the Chrome console also shows this

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list.
>   Method JSON is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in
>   preflight response.

But when I tried the endpoint in `http://www.test-cors.org`, it looks okay, though.

```
Sending GET request to https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list

Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: load

XHR status: 200
XHR status text: OK
XHR exposed response headers:

    Content-Type: application/json
```

Here's the response header for OPTIONS

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 02:16:30 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-amzn-RequestId: d2ab4dce-c3fe-11e6-bcee-6767a7211424
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 c038088d4b94486d7346fd44d03188a0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 30nHstKUhLwnHDwYEF3VdugR3JsuXHvUScBRDRFHRhimPW_DHS7RPQ==
```

Here's for the GET

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 158
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 02:17:17 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-amzn-RequestId: ee6c19a6-c3fe-11e6-a0dc-01a17c495e09
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5854a02d-ba86e18abb4d47eb5094343b
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 18101d17be4ee51b5a03b68cfed50445.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 8K8NhwXGzhqR4bYLSFrRglogJQmQq3D3GJ2P4FrYoO-naDs-I55haA==
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making the request using a request method of 'json' (via the `type` property); `'json'` is not a valid [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Instead of `type: 'json'` you probably want `dataType: 'json'`.

The `type` property can be used to specify the [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) (eg `'GET'`), though it was deprecated in favour of the `method` property as of [jquery v1.9](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://dgyoawr9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/comments/list',
method: 'GET', // not necessary since it will default to 'GET'
dataType: 'json', // use dataType, not type, to specify expected response data type
crossDomain: true,
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) {
    alert('test');
}});
```

Comment: Ouch, it does help. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot. I feel so embarrassed.